How to start my text within the align environment from the left margin of page without separating the equation line and text line?
I am writing a journal for publication and because of the page limit I have to write text within the equation line. Here is my code:
    \documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %\usepackage{epstopdf}% not needed
    \usepackage{romannum}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    %\usepackage{romannum}% twice?
    \usepackage{lipsum}% to see in context
    \newcommand{\m}{\tilde{m}}% not \def
    \begin{document}    
    \lipsum 
     \begin{align}
        \mbox{ Next,}\ m_{BCH} - m_{ar} & = 8 k^2 - 1 - (k+1) \sqrt{n} \nonumber \\
        & =  8 k^2 - \sqrt{n} k - (\sqrt{n} + 1)\nonumber\\
        & =  8 (k - r_2) ( k + r_2 - \sqrt{n}/8), \label{eq:181}
    \end{align} 
    \end{document}

But as you can see in the attached image that the text "Next" is not aligned with the left page margin. I looks like I am starting a new paragraph with "Next" which is not the case. Can somebody help me to start the text "Next" from left margin of the page without separating the text line and equation line?

As a user commented to use flalign , I want to say that I tried it but it didn't work.

If you write a paragraph instead of using lipsum, the same happens? Also you are missing a documentclass

use flalign (full length align) but also you should provide an example, so people can test answers.

@Mane32 ; Yes, same happens. I edited the code, please see it.

@DavidCarlisle ; It didn't work.

You can use flalign to spread the alignment "full length" and put the text in a new first column.

  \documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %\usepackage{epstopdf}% not needed
    \usepackage{romannum}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    %\usepackage{romannum}% twice?
    \usepackage{lipsum}% to see in context
    \newcommand{\m}{\tilde{m}}% not \def
    \begin{document}    
    \lipsum
     \begin{flalign}
      &\mbox{Next,}&\ m_{BCH} - m_{ar} & = 8 k^2 - 1 - (k+1) \sqrt{n} \nonumber \\
     && & =  8 k^2 - \sqrt{n} k - (\sqrt{n} + 1)\nonumber\\
      && & =  8 (k - r_2) ( k + r_2 - \sqrt{n}/8), \label{eq:181}
    \end{flalign} 
    \end{document}


With your code, the distance horizontal distance between $Next,$ and $m_{BCH}$ is too wide. Is there a way to avoid that?

Add morre &&s to the right.  Since they all expand the same amount, the more you have, the smaller they get.
